# Java. Regex matcher not working, with regex which works in c# or vb.net

Tags: java, regex

I'm developing an application which parses through scan reports, so I'm using regex to filter them. My regex is `\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\s{1,10}\\d{1,4}\\sms.*`
(with escaping slashes) and the text which I'm filtering looks like

```
172.20.4.3      0 ms            k2g-dhcp.somedomain.jp    [n/s]           00:1C:C4:5B:12:F2                [n/a]                               
172.20.4.4      [n/a]           [n/s]                   [n/s]           [n/s]
```

I've tested the given regex and it matches normally, but in Java it just doesn't.
Here is my code:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\s{1,10}\\d{1,4}\\sms.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(data);
while(mat.find())
{
    System.out.println("Found matches!"); // Code never gets here
}
System.out.println("Done!");
```

Comment: This might help you: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/

Comment: the code works for me. it prints "Found matches!" for the input "172.20.4.3     0 ms            k2g-dhcp.somedomain.jp     [n/s]               00:1C:C4:5B:12:F2               [n/a]   "

Comment: @IJP for me it doesn't... i don't know why.

Comment: I get it working as well (using planetregex). Is the data exactly the same as posted?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "172.20.4.3     0 ms            k2g-dhcp.somedomain.jp     [n/s]               00:1C:C4:5B:12:F2               [n/a]   ";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\s{1,10}\\d{1,4}\\sms.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(data);
        while(mat.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Found matches!"); // Code never gets here
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");

    }

}
```